# Query that works in mongo does not work in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm making the following query in mongoose:

```
Schedule.find({
    'operative.from': { $lte: '2015-09-07T00:00:25+00:00' },
    'operative.to': { $gte: '2015-09-07T23:59:25+00:00' },
    'operative.weekdays': { $in: [ 1 ] } })
    .exec()
    .then(function () { … })
```

It returns no results. What confuses me is that if I run the exact same query on the Mongo Shell, it returns ~200 results as expected.

I've tried removing the conditions until it returned some results, and what's confusing mongoose are the two dates queries.

The relevant schema for those fields is the following:

```
operative: {
   from: Date,
   to: Date,

   // weekdayds the flight is operated, Sunday = 0
   weekdays: []
 }
```

I've also ensured that the queries without date conditions return the expected results, and they do. Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Have you tried _new Date()_ around your dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue is not with the query itself but with the schema:

In another field, not relevant to the query, I was specifying a path as follows:

```
aircraft: {
  type: String,
  owner: String
}
```

Using a reserved key `type` caused a validation error. For performance reasons I populated the collection skipping mongoose validation on the documents, so this issue went unnoticed.

After changing the `aircraft.type` path to `type: { type: String }` the document validation was successful and the query fulfilling correctly.

<strike>I've also reported on the Mongoose repository the fact that validation errors can silently fail your queries, which is unacceptable.</strike>

**EDIT:**

As the maintainer pointed me out, this is by design in Mongoose. Use the [strict option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) to have the appropriate errors thrown

Answer (score -1):

You are passing two strings to your queries where mongoose expects js Date objects. It will work when you use `new Date('2015-08-12T00:00:25')`

Comment: That's simply not true. Mongoose is expecting a vlid Date objet OR anything that can be converted to a valid Date object, such an Array or ISO String.

Comment: well, I have several large mongoose apps in production that all handle loads of date queries and they work very well with Dates for queries. Have you tried it? I just think it is better to do explicit casting then relying on some implicit code...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either of the two ways. You way is very explicit but mine relies on a solid standard (ISO-8601). Both will work as expected every time (and it's not the source of my problem, see my own answer for details). It would be interesting, on the other hand, to see if there is any performance difference between the two, I guess it depends on how Mongoose handles the query